# Unable to get a Java API without obsoletes by Javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I regularly observe obsolete classes and methods in Java API.

I did not find Java API without obsoletes.
It suggests me that you need to filter Java API by your browser to get it more readable.
Javascript is apparently a good solution in filtering Java API.

**How can you get Java API without Obseletes by Javascript or by other method?**

[edit after the first answer]

I downloaded the javadocs to the folder docs. I run

```
javadoc -nodeprecatedlist docs/
```

I get the error

```
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "docs/"
1 error
```

Comment: Are you aware that there is no relationship between Java and JavaScript, except for the name?

Comment: @John: I did not know that exactly. I have had the idea that JavaScript and Java are similar, but JavaScript is specifically targeted for browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can regenerate the javadoc from the sources with the -nodeprecated option

Comment: @Maurice: Do you mean with Javascript? Could you give an example?

Comment: No, sorry, it's a bit more complicated that that: you will need to download the jdk sources from sun's web site and apply the javadoc command to them. This will produce a new set of html files.